# Existing Triangles Cannot be Removed

Tags: d3.js

I bind triangles with data in D3.js. But the triganle cannot be removed with the data. The rectangles are okay. Complete code is attached!

```js
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width",  250)
  .attr("height", 250);

function render(data){       
  var tris = svg.selectAll("tri").data(data);
  tris.enter().append("path");
  tris.attr("d", function(d) {
    var x1 = (0.4 - 0.2 * (d - 1)) * 250, y1 = 0.3 * 250;
    var x2 = (0.5 - 0.2 * (d - 1)) * 250, y2 = 0.1 * 250;
    var x3 = (0.6 - 0.2 * (d - 1)) * 250, y3 = 0.3 * 250;
    return "M" + x1 + " " + y1 + " L" + x2 + " " + y2 + " L" + x3 + " " + y3 + "Z";
    });
  tris.exit().remove();
        
  var rects = svg.selectAll("rect").data(data);
  rects.enter().append("rect");
  rects.attr("y", 50)
    .attr("width",  20)
    .attr("height", 20)
    .attr("x", function(d) { return d * 40; });
  rects.exit().remove();
}
render([1, 2, 3]);
render([1, 2]); 
render([1]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no SVG element called `<tri>`. Your enter selection works because you can select *anything* in your data binding function. As there is nothing named "tri" in the whole DOM (be it a tag, a class, an ID, whatever...), your enter selection is **never empty** and your exit selection is **never populated**.

That being said, an easy solution is selecting by class...

```
var tris = svg.selectAll(".tri").data(data);
```

And setting this class in your enter selection:

```
tris.enter().append("path").attr("class", "tri");
```

Here is your code with the changes:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width",  250)
  .attr("height", 250);

function render(data){       
  var tris = svg.selectAll(".tri").data(data);
  tris.enter().append("path").attr("class","tri");
  tris.attr("d", function(d) {
    var x1 = (0.4 - 0.2 * (d - 1)) * 250, y1 = 0.3 * 250;
    var x2 = (0.5 - 0.2 * (d - 1)) * 250, y2 = 0.1 * 250;
    var x3 = (0.6 - 0.2 * (d - 1)) * 250, y3 = 0.3 * 250;
    return "M" + x1 + " " + y1 + " L" + x2 + " " + y2 + " L" + x3 + " " + y3 + "Z";
    });
  tris.exit().remove();
        
  var rects = svg.selectAll("rect").data(data);
  rects.enter().append("rect");
  rects.attr("y", 50)
    .attr("width",  20)
    .attr("height", 20)
    .attr("x", function(d) { return d * 40; });
  rects.exit().remove();
}

render([1, 2, 3]);
setTimeout(() => render([1, 2]), 1000); 
setTimeout(() => render([1]), 2000)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: or `svg.selectAll("path").data(data)`

Comment: Yes, same principle. But it's important to explain to OP *why* the triangles were appended. If it was `selectAll("pinkUnicorns")` it would work as well.